# Restricting access of other processes when creating shared memory

Tags: winapi, shared-memory

In Windows, I would like to offer my software as a "data provider" so that other developers can read the data by using their own software, in same PC.
To achieve this I picked up the shared memory approach, going testbed, and got some concerned about security.

My software creates shared memory by calling `CreateFileMapping` function of Windows API, with `PAGE_READWRITE` parameter.
After that, other process might get the shared memory by calling `OpenFileMapping` function. In this case, I would like to restrict this guy to call the `OpenFileMapping` function with `FILE_MAP_READ` parameter only(otherwise it should return `false`).

How to achieve this? Carefully guessing the parameter `lpFileMappingAttributes` of the `CreateFileMapping` in host side is the key, but none of my attempts have succeeded. What am I missing?

Comment: you can set security descriptor on section, say `"D:P(A;;GR;;;WD)"` which allow open object only with read access. of course this not revent some app from change sd

Comment: Remember, however, that windows security is token-based. With shared memory you will simply not be able to secure against any thread presenting the appropriate token. This sounds like a way to secure against inadvertent changes rather than anything actively malicious.

Comment: File mapping can be used to share a file or memory between two or more processes. Whether you want to restrict access of other processes? If so, what is the point of your choice to use shared memory?

Comment: I would like to provide quite large data stream as an host process. After some research, I thought I could solve this by supporting the concept of 'Programmatic Access' in my software.  Message Queue or Dedicated Streaming Server could be considered, but the range of data provided by my software is limited to the same PC, so I chose the Shared Memory method.

Comment: Protection is a system feature that avoids processes from creating arbitrary access to resources belonging to other processes. As far as I'm concerned, sharing and protection are incompatible; sharing enable access, whereas protection confine it.